# Ingestion of cellulose digesting prokaryotes?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, nutrition

If humans digest cellulose digesting prokaryotes,  can  we start digesting cellulose like cows?

Comment: How would we get the three additional stomach chambers, and the time to eat this stuff?